# Having filtering functionality in the sidebar global component while rendering the products in the products component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, components, facet

I have a global component of Sidebar that handles the filtering functionality and the Products component that does the rendering of the products. I have filtering implemented in the Sidebar with an API that works perfectly, but I cannot figure out how to make it render the filtered results in products component. I cannot create a parent component as sidebar is a global component and in that case I have a duplicated sidebar.
I tried to use context but I'm having problems.
The issue is that even when using context I still have to render the component in one way or another and it appears on the page that I do not want since Sidebar is global and then I have it duplicated.
Any suggestions are very much appreciated.
I'm building in next.js v12.

Comment: Could you clarify what are the issues that you are having with useContext hook ?

Comment: what are the issues that you are having with useContext hook ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I clarified the problem with useContext @MobinSalehi